# MySQL Count rows from query with left joins

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a query that looks like this:

```
 Select x.date, x.id, x.phone,
    x.product, xy.policy,xy.date 
 from (y left join z 
            on y.customer_id=z.customer_id)
    left join x 
       on x.id=z.id 
    left join xy 
       on xy.id=x.id 
 where x.date > '2000-01-01'  
    and y.detail =foo 
    and xy.policy like 'foo_____'  
    and xy.policy_type = foo;
```

How can I count the number of rows this returns?

I tried using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS but I can't quite fit it into this query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Stefan.

Comment: can you outline the query and add some code tags around please?

Comment: do you want to have another column for the total rows of the result? eg `ID, ColA, TotalResult`, `1,1,4`,`1,2,4`,`1,3,4`,`1,4,4`?

Comment: No thanks, I just want to get a count of what this returns. Basically if I could wrap a count() around this I would be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM y
  JOIN z
    ON y.customer_id = z.customer_id
  JOIN x
    ON x.id = z.id
  JOIN xy
    ON xy.id = x.id
 WHERE x.date > '2000-01-01'
   AND y.detail = foo
   AND xy.policy LIKE 'foo_____'
   AND xy.policy_type = foo
;
```

(Note that I've taken the liberty of changing your `LEFT JOIN`s to regular `JOIN`s, since the `WHERE` clause prevented them from actually functioning as `LEFT JOIN`s anyway. If you want real `LEFT JOIN`s, you can move conditions from the `WHERE` clause into `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM y
  LEFT
  JOIN z
    ON z.customer_id = y.customer_id
  LEFT
  JOIN x
    ON x.id = z.id
   AND x.date > '2000-01-01'
  LEFT
  JOIN xy
    ON xy.id = x.id
   AND xy.policy LIKE 'foo_____'
   AND xy.policy_type = foo
 WHERE y.detail = foo
;
```

)

Comment: @StefanHanotin: O.K.; did you understand my explanation about the `LEFT JOIN`s and the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I did understand your comment. Your top query worked as expected. Not sure why the bottom one is getting a different count.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is just add a subquery...

```
 Select x.date, x.id, x.phone,
    x.product, xy.policy,xy.date,
    (Select Count(*) 
     From (y left join z on y.customer_id=z.customer_id)
        left join x on x.id=z.id 
        left join xy  on xy.id=x.id 
     where x.date > '2000-01-01'  
       and y.detail =foo 
       and xy.policy like 'foo_____'  
       and xy.policy_type = foo) RecordCount  
 from (y left join z 
            on y.customer_id=z.customer_id)
    left join x 
       on x.id=z.id 
    left join xy 
       on xy.id=x.id 
 where x.date > '2000-01-01'  
    and y.detail =foo 
    and xy.policy like 'foo_____'  
    and xy.policy_type = foo;
```

If all you want is the count, then:

```
 Select Count(*) 
 From (y left join z on y.customer_id=z.customer_id)
    left join x on x.id=z.id 
    left join xy  on xy.id=x.id 
 where x.date > '2000-01-01'  
   and y.detail =foo 
   and xy.policy like 'foo_____'  
   and xy.policy_type = foo
```

Comment: Hi Charles, your query is returning the correct count but all I want is the count. I don't want the table. I just want a single figure that counts the number of rows.